# BroadcastReceiver not firing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

my receiver is not firing, code below:

AndroidManifest

```
<recevier android:name=".NoticeReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.clublifestyle.NoticeService.BROADCAST" />
    </intent-filter>            
</recevier>
```

NoticeReceiver.java

```
public class NoticeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "ASDASD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

CLMainActivity.java

```
public class CLMainActivity extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.createTabs();

        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, NoticeReceiver.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(i2);
    }
}
```

Can you help me to find out why? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to also set the action for the `Intent` *i2*:

```
Intent i2 = new Intent();
i2.setAction("com.clublifestyle.NoticeService.BROADCAST");
this.sendBroadcast(i2);
```

**EDIT**

There is a typo in your manifest. You have the `<receiver>` tag written as `<recevier>`. Your app sees no `<receiver>`

Comment: @kenyi  I found the source of your problem. In your manifest the correct word is `receiver` and not as you wrote it `recevier` , now your app simply doesn't see the receiver.

Comment: A big thanks! Seems like Eclipse doesn't detect error in this typo.